# SQL Server 2005/2008 - Double Click to open table / view first 200 results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, configuration, double-click

Is there a way to configure the shortcuts etc in SQL Server 2005 / 2008 as per the headline.

When I doubleclick on a table, I typically want to open it to view the information within, not to just access the next level on the explorer. When I do this on a procedure, I usually want to modify it. This question is one year overdue as this issue has bothered me for quite some time.

Is there a way to change the action for a doubleclick on these items? It's less than 1% of the time when I actually have a use for the doubleclick -> go up 1 level on explorer functionality. Which to me seems like an unnecessary inconvenience in the usability of said program. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get the same result that you want:

1. Install [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/)
2. In SSMS, go to the SSMS Tools menu > Run Custom Stripts > Options
3. Add a new custom script "Top 200 rows", and add the following Sql script:

   SELECT TOP 200 * FROM |NodeName|
4. Click "Enabled on..." and select "Table"